# "Kindly notice that" or "Kindly note that"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sometimes I received emails start with "Kindly notice", and other times "Kindly note", I checked the two meaning on the dictionaries and it seem both of them can be verb and they have similar meanings.

> - Dear, Kindly/please **notice** that we changed .....
> - Dear, Kindly/please **note** that we changed .....

> notice (verb): to see or become conscious of something or someone. [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notice?)
>
> note (verb): to notice something / to give your attention to something by discussing it or making a written record of it. [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/note)

Which one should I use in when I write emails? and what is the difference in meaning? Are they interchangeable?

Note: there are some posts on the internet regards this, but there are conflicting views.

In the same context, should I use:

> - **I noticed** there are some changes on the system ...
> - **I noted** there are some changes on the system ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definitions of the verbs that you quoted explain the difference- in particular, the part **to give your attention to something by discussing it or making a written record of it.**

If you want to ask somebody to make pay attention to something, to remember it or to make a written note of it, you would say

> Kindly note that...

If you want to say that something caught your attention, you should say

> I noticed that...

If you want to say that you gave something your attention, that you made a point of remembering something or that you wrote it down, you would say

> I noted that...

Comment: Thank you, Is “Kindly notice that ...” wrong?

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect, but it's inappropriate for that context. Have a look at some of these usages: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kindly%20notice%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 6):

Although the words are very closely related, we do not ask a person with whom we are corresponding to "kindly notice" anything. That locution is simply not used.

To **notice** something is to become aware of it *unintentionally*.  The thing "catches our eye".

If we open the refrigerator door to get the milk, we might notice that the bottle of orange juice is almost empty. *We cannot ask someone to become unintentionally aware of something.*

Rather, we say **kindly note**, which can be paraphrased "please be aware of this pertinent fact".

P.S. Imperative **Notice that...** and **Notice how...** are often used, but  almost invariably in the context of saying words to the effect "while we are looking at X, **notice how** Y...". In other words, it's an analogue of noticing that the orange juice is bottle is nearly empty when you've stuck your head in the fridge to get the milk.

Comment: I would use a phrase with "draw your attention to" rather than asking people to notice, but you can say something like "(I hope) you will notice".

Comment: "I hope you will notice..." is not something I'd want to be told.